# Extra columns found in iris dataset

Tags: r, iris-dataset

So I am new to R and have just begun my practice.
My first command is `library(datasets)`

Then I am doing `head(iris)`
However, I am getting virginica instead of setosa.

[image]

when I do `plot(iris)` I am getting this plot with 64 boxes. However, other people are getting only 25 boxes as ususal

[image: Plot with 64 boxes]

Then I do

```
plot(iris$Species)
```

And i get the following error:

```
> plot(iris$Species)
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Can anyone explain why am I getting these unusual results?

Comment: It sounds like you may have modified/replaced the default iris dataset at some point. What does `find("iris")` return for you? If it's not `package:datasets`, try to remove your local copy with `rm(iris)`. Or start again in a fresh R session. Or specifically access the version from `datasets` with `datasets::iris`

Comment: You have added some extra columns in your `iris` dataset. Restart your R session and try again.